# glBufferSubData() and glBindArray()

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have two methods:

1. `opengl_init()`
2. `opengl_draw()`

In the first one I initialize an empty `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` because I want to update my point coordinates each frame.

Everything works if in `opengl_draw()` method I keep commented out `//glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)`

Normally I use this function when I draw elements statically in the last line of the `opengl_init()` method.

**Question:**

Could you explain why commenting out `glBindBuffer()` function positions are updated every frame, and if I use `glBindBuffer()` function objects are draw statically (no change of y coordinate) even if I use `glBufferSubData()` in a while loop every frame?

I also do not understand why I need to write glBindVertexArray(0); in the last line of opengl_init() method. I used this line from learnopengl tutorials.

My working code:

```
    void opengl_init()
    {
        //vertex array
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        //vertex buffer
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        //-> keep this function NULL to dynamically draw vertices glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); // target | size | data (poinnting to first element e.g. glm::value_ptr(vertices[0])) | usage
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertex), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //set attributes that corresponds to layout id in the vertex shader
        // set the vertex attribute pointers
        // vertex Positions
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (void*)0);
        // vertex normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (void*)offsetof(vertex, color));

        //bind buffers vao | vbo | ibo
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    // render the mesh
    void opengl_draw(opengl_shaders::shader& shader)
    {
        for (auto& v : vertices)
            v.position.y += 0.001;
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertex), &vertices[0]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.size());
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
```

Comment: But if you call `glBindVertexArray(0)` at the end of `opengl_draw` then the next time `opengl_draw` is called `glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...` will fail because nothing is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, right?  Have you tried using `glGetError` to check for errors?  Apologies if I've misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glBufferSubData` requires that `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound to a buffer. `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` binds it to nothing.

Assuming nothing else in this code touches `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, commenting that line leaves it bound to `vbo`, which means that the `glBufferSubData` call knows which buffer to update.

It is best to be explicit and bind the correct buffer before you touch it. In this case, inside `opengl_draw`.

If you find all of this confusing, know that modern OpenGL also has direct state access, which does not require a separate `glBindBuffer`:

```
// Note we pass vbo directly instead of GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
glNamedBufferSubData(vbo, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertex), &vertices[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
Which OpenGL version does this function belongs to?
Because I get access violation exception.

And when you say "glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); binds it to nothing." for static drawing to what normally I must bind the buffer or I can simply delete this line?

Comment: It was made core in 4.5. Your system might still support the extension (with an EXT suffix) even if it does not ship 4.5

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL [`glNamedBufferSubData`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) was introduced in OpenGL 4.5 .

Comment: The VAO remembers which VBO to source information from for each vertex attribute. You do not need to have the VBO bound for drawing

Comment: @Botje

This does not work. If I run the my code two times, then the first one is always overridden. Is there any proper explanation how to use glBufferSubData for multiple arays?

Comment: I don't know what else there is to say beyond "make sure the correct buffer is bound before you call glBufferSubData". I have no idea what you mean by "the first one is always overridden". Suggest you ask a new question and refer to this one.